# parseInt() behaves differently

Tags: javascript

I am using the following condition in javascript to filter my options based on postcode.

```
if (parseInt(postcode, 10) > 99 && parseInt(postcode, 10) < 10000 && postcode != '') {
    // code goes here...
}
```

where postcode can be any Australian postcode. It works for all except some random postcodes like `0852`/`0840`/`4840`. I am not sure whether it works for all postcodes I just checked for random postcodes.

Comment: Did you try `alert(parseInt(postcode, 10))` for the offending random codes?

Comment: `0852` treated as octal number

Comment: Note: Older browsers will use the octal radix (8) as default when the string begins with "0". As of ECMAScript 5, the default is the decimal radix (10).

Comment: but radix is 10, why does it take octal????? It wouldn't.

Comment: parseInt('0852/0840/4840',10) = 852

@OP: Please describe what output do you expect vs what you get

Comment: It's clear from the question that a radix of 10 is already being used. What is not clear is exactly what the value of `postcode` is, what happens and what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and it works absolutely fine for the postcodes you mentioned. Perhaps there are issues in other browsers - that I have not checked anything save or the latest Firefox.

Either way, please make sure the `parseInt` returns what you expect. You could do something like this:

```
var parsed = parseInt(postcode, 10);
if (parsed > 99 && parsed < 10000 && postcode != '') {
    // code goes here...
} else {
    console.log(postcode, parsed);
}
```

The above will print the bad values to the console and you will probably find out what's wrong. Maybe they return `NaN`? Maybe the input wasn't trimmed?

By the way, I would rework your condition. `postcode != ''` is a narrow case; what if you input `'abc'`? All such values will be `NaN` after passing them through `parseInt`, so you could as well do something like this:

```
var parsed = parseInt(postcode, 10);
if (!!parsed && parsed > 99 && parsed < 10000) {
    // code goes here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I figured this out. However the issue was with my google api not with parseint(). Thanks anyways.